# How to transfer data which is consumed from webservice using "Service" in android?

Tags: android, service, data-transfer

Right now i am consuming one web-service using Service.Now i would like to send that data(which i've consumed from Main
Activity) to the next activity, has any one have any idea about it

suggestion please

Thanks for your preciuos time!..

**Please find my sources for reference**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AlarmManager alarm;
PendingIntent pintent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // Start service every 20 seconds
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),10* 1000, pintent);

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    alarm.cancel(pintent);
    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));

     }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {


String result_data = "";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
    Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Authentication_Class task = new Authentication_Class();
    task.execute();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Servics Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

public class Authentication_Class extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Call_service();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    private void Call_service() throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    String URL          =   "";
    String METHOD_NAME  =   "";
    String NAMESPACE    =   "";
    String SOAPACTION   =   "";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    // Add parameters if available 

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL,15000);
    try {

        httpTransportSE.call(SOAPACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        result_data = String.valueOf(result);
        System.out.println(">>-- RESPONSE    :    " +result_data);


    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data that you want to retrieve has to be consumed directly by an Activity or any UI, you have to use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) to consume it and no `Service`. Then you can pass the data to another activity using an Intent `Bundle`, for example. If the data is a global session identifier, you can store it in a global variable accessible by all your activities but you also have to store it on disk, so that you can properly restore it with your application after it has been killed if the OS needed more memory.

If the data has to be loaded in the background, to do some background processing or pre-caching independently from the UI, you have to use an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which will create a background thread for you automatically and you can put your download code in [`onHandleIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) directly (there is no need to create any `AsyncTask` in a Service).

It all depends on your use case.

Comment: Can you please give one sample if you have, because im newbie to the "Service" concept

Comment: There are a lot of samples in the Android SDK and a complete documentation is available to explain how Services work in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html. You must first determine if you need a Service in your application or not. Most applications don't.

Comment: Why i am preferring service because, right now i am having one News showing project,in that project i would like to consume all the data in background which are all required for the project while showing the Splash screen at first later i'll show the data on next activities like that i've planned so far. But i dont know the actual procedure to do News app. Is there any procedure to create a News app?

Comment: You could load all the data during the splash screen using an AsyncTask or Loader and when it's done you quit the splash screen, then you don't need a Service. But splash screens are generally a bad idea.
To sum it up, if you want the data to be loaded when the app is not showing, use a Service, else don't.